# How to create web part to insert data in custom list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm quite new to sharepoint and what I want to develop is this:

I have a number of custom lists that are connetted between them like a relational DB. What I want to do is to develop a web part that will be able to insert data in all these different lists.

Can someone please give me some hints to where to start from? If there are some tutorials or how tos. Thanks a lot.

AB

Comment: Can you specify which version of share point? 2007 or 2010 and which version of the release, I.e moss or share point services or foundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice article about adding items to custom sharepoint list [you can check it !](http://www.fivenumber.com/custom-webpart-inserts-items-into-sharepoint-custom-list/)

Goes like

```
SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;  
SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;  
SPList myList = myWeb.Lists["Custom List"];  
SPListItem myListItem = myList.Items.Add(); 
myListItem["Title"] = oTextTitle.Text.ToString();  
myListItem["Employee Name"] = oTextName.Text.ToString();  
myListItem["Designation"] = oTextDesignation.Text.ToString();
```